# Samples don't work in Google NaCl rev 18

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm trying to use the latest Google NaCl SDK. Following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper18/devguide/tutorial

I downloaded the naclsdk tool from their site, ran update, and got a pepper_18 folder.

I set NACL_SDK_ROOT to the pepper_18 folder, went in to 'examples' and ran make. Everything seemed to compile just fine.

I started Chrome, looked in about: flags and about: plugins, and verified that NaCl is enabled. I installed the SDK Examples app (from: https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper18/sdk/examples) and that works just fine.

Then I tried to run my locally built and hosted examples, going to http://localhost: 5301. The HTML loads fine but the NaCl content does not load. In the hello world examples, it says "Status: LOADING..." forever.

I double checked the HTTP server logs and I don't see any errors there. Is there another place I should be looking for logged errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check for version mismatch**

In Chrome navigate to about:version and check that the major version of Chrome is at least that of the Pepper version you used to build your examples.

**Check the JavaScript console in Chrome for any errors**

You can find it by clicking the wrench icon in the upper right-hand corner in Chrome and selecting Tools -> JavaScript Console.

**Inspect the NaCl module for further information**

In the JavaScript console, you can also inspect the embed element of the NaCl module. E.g., if the embed tag has `id="nacl_module"` you can inspect it by typing

> theModule = document.getElementById('nacl_module');
>
> theModule.lastError;

**Check Chrome's output to stdout/stderr**

On Mac or Linux start Chrome from the terminal and look at the output on the console. E.g., on the Mac, you'd typically go

> /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-nacl

On Windows, Chrome does not write to the terminal if started from a command prompt. For this reason you need to redirect stdout/stderr from Chrome by setting the environment variables NACLLOG, NACL_EXE_STDOUT, and NACL_EXE_STDERR. Point them to *different* files, e.g.,

> NACLLOG = c:\my_project\nacl.log
>
> NACL_EXE_STDOUT = c:\my_project\nacl_stdout.log
>
> NACL_EXE_STDERR = c:\my_project\nacl_stderr.log

Then (re-)start Chrome (making sure these environment variables are in effect).

**Connect a debugger**

Instructions on using the debugging support (currently only 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Linux) are available at https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper18/beta-docs/debugging.

**Restarting Chrome means closing *all* windows**

When developing for Native Client one often restarts Chrome. It is important to close all Chrome windows; otherwise it hasn't actually restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! It turned out to be a version mismatch with Chrome 17. I switched to pepper_16 and that worked.

Comment: @West, I'm see this  http://i.stack.imgur.com/l47Sg.png but why does `document.getElementById('nacl_module');`  gives null?

Answer (score 1):

I muddled through a few issues which I will document in case they help others:

- Neglected to 'make' the examples (got a clue to make them from the asker's description).
- Chrome would not let me run non-store chrome apps. Went to `chrome://flags` and enabled `Native Client` and `Native Client GDB-based debugging`.
- The JavaScript console said the demo's nmf file under .../debug/ was missing. I changed the make config to build Debug instead of Release based on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/RwmaH6og9XY).
- Chrome console complained `NativeClient: NaCl module load failed: ServiceRuntime: failed to start; NaCl's GDB debug stub requires --no-sandbox flag on Windows. See crbug…`. Tried running Chrome from cmd with `--no-sandbox`. This results in an alert `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --nosandbox. Stability and security will suffer.` The aforementioned error went away, but the examples still would not run - no UI.
- Went back to `chrome://flags` and disabled `Native Client GDB-based debugging`.

Then most of the examples worked. The `Google Drive` demo complains `Error: must be run as a packged app.`

Answer (score 0):

have you confirmed that you've run httpd.py from the examples folder? This script creates the localhost:5103 server that the apps can be ran from.

Also, what OS are you using?

~Main